# I can't redirect to app setting in react native (android 12)

Tags: android, react-native

how to redirect to app settings in react native for android 12 only?

```
NativeModules.OpenSettings.openNetworkSettings(() => null);
```

i can't use that code right now

```
import { openSettings } from 'react-native-permissions';
openSettings();
```

this also not working for me

Answer (score 1):

have you tried this

```
const Screen = () => (
  <Button
    title="Open Settings"
    onPress={() => {
      Linking.openSettings();
    }}
  />
);
```

don't forget to import

```
import { Button, Linking } from "react-native";
```

Answer (score 1):

> First you have go to the official documentation of React Native there
> you find the solution of this question.

[Documentation of React Native Linking](https://reactnative.dev/docs/linking)

> Code:

```
<TouchableOpacity
            onPress={() => {
              Linking.openSettings();
            }}
            style={{
              paddingHorizontal: 80,
              paddingVertical: 10,
              backgroundColor: '#326A81',
            }}>
            <Text style={{color: 'white'}}>Open Setting</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
```

Answer (score 1):

The below should work for both android and ios

```
import { Linking, Platform } from 'react-native';


const handleOpenSettings = () => {
    if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
      Linking.openURL('app-settings:');
    } else {
      Linking.openSettings();
    }
};
```